# Insert data in table from 2 other tables with subquery

Tags: sql, database, subquery

I have 3 tables, named tblProducten, tblCategorie and tblProductCategorie.

tblProductenen has:

- PK_producten_ID (Primary key, A.I.)
- ProductNaam (products name, VARCHAR)

This table is filled with smartphone or normal phone data(for example "iPhone4", "Nokia 3310")

tblCategorie has:

- PK_Categorie_ID (Primary key, A.I.)
- Naam_Categorie(Categorie name, VARCHAR)

This table is filled with Category's(for example "smartphones", "phones", "extra")

tblProductCategorie has:

- PK_Product_Categorie_ID(Primary key, A.I.)
- ProductNaam (Categorie name, VARCHAR)
- tblProductenen_PK_Producten_ID
- tblCategorie_PK_Categorie_ID

Now I want to Enter the product named "iPhone4" and the category of the product "smartPhone" into the CategorieProduct tabel.

I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblProductCategorie (
  SELECT PK_producten_ID FROM tblProducten
  WHERE ProductNaam = "iPhone4",
    SELECT PK_Categorie_ID FROM tblCategorie
    WHERE Naam_Categorie = "smartphone"
)
```

But was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tblProductCategorie(ProductNaam, tblProductenen_PK_Producten_ID, tblCategorie_PK_Categorie_ID)
SELECT distinct ###, PK_producten_ID, PK_Categorie_ID
FROM tblProducten, tblCategorie 
WHERE ProductNaam = "iPhone4" AND Naam_Categorie = "smartphone";
```

what name do you really want to insert into table? product name, category name or both?

Comment: I have for example allot of phones, and allot of categories for the phones, and since this is a many to many relationship, I'll need to create another table to combine the Primary keys, and with your code, with small adjustments, it worked! Thanks allot !

Answer (score 1):

the way you inserting your values has two major problems, you don't specify the column list

```
insert into tablename (column1, column2, etc)values ( 1, 2)
```

and second you don't put all args in your columns.

```
INSERT INTO tblProductCategorie( PK_Product_Categorie_ID, ProductNaam, tblProductenen_PK_Producten_ID, tblCategorie_PK_Categorie_ID) (SELECT PK_producten_ID FROM tblProducten WHERE ProductNaam = "iPhone4", SELECT PK_Categorie_ID FROM tblCategorie WHERE Naam_Categorie = "smartphone")
```

should require something like :

```
INSERT INTO tblProductCategorie( PK_Product_Categorie_ID, ProductNaam, tblProductenen_PK_Producten_ID, tblCategorie_PK_Categorie_ID)( "iPhone4", SELECT PK_producten_ID FROM tblProducten WHERE ProductNaam = "iPhone4", SELECT PK_Categorie_ID FROM tblCategorie WHERE Naam_Categorie = "smartphone")
```

good luck ;)

Comment: Looks good too, but, the other guys answer was quicker and also did the trick :/, thanks tho !